# UIPickerView Row Color

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Does anyone know how to change the color of a row (or row background) in the UIPickerView control from the iPhone SDK? Similiar to the below title for row, however I would also like to change the color of the row:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can return an arbitrary view in the delegate's -pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView: method, documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:).

Answer (score 14):

Thanks Noah, that's exactly what I needed. I wanted to add the code here just in case anyone else needs (or wants to comment on :)

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 15, 15);
    UIImageView *label = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame] **autorelease**];

    if (row == 0)
    {
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    if (row == 1)
    {
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    if (row == 2)
    {
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }   
    return label;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `reusingView` parameter ? It is similar to UITableView's reuse pool...

Comment: Is there a way to customize the selection bar which is shown as gray gradient in a UIPickerView?

Answer (score 3):

I implemented the following based on Sean's answer:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGRect rowFrame = CGRectMake(00.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component].frame.size.width, [pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component].frame.size.height);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rowFrame];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f];

    // This is an array I pass to the picker in prepareForSegue:sender:
    label.text = [self.values objectAtIndex:row];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    // This is an array I pass to the picker in prepareForSegue:sender:
    if ([self.backgroundColors count]) {
        label.backgroundColor = [self.backgroundColors objectAtIndex:row];

        // self.lightColors is an array I instantiate in viewDidLoad: self.lightColors = @[ [UIColor yellowColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor whiteColor] ];
        label.textColor = [self.lightColors containsObject:label.backgroundColor] ? [UIColor blackColor] : [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    return label;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    UILabel *labelSelected = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
    [labelSelected setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

}
```

And

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    UILabel *label = (id)view;

    if (!label){

      label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
      label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
      pickerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
      label.text=[self pickerView:pickerView titleForRow:row forComponent:component];
      label.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    }
    return label;
}
```

Answer (score -7):

Do this:

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourcolorColor];
```