# how to change the default color of selection bar in PickerView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uipickerview

I have a pickerView in my selection but the client's requirement is the greenish color of the selction bar of pickerview but I don't know how to change the color of selection bar.

pls help me.
thanx in advance.

Comment: This may lead to some answers for you.
[stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310786/uipickerview-row-color

Answer (score 2):

gdmorn!!!!

Try to do this ,it may be Help to you...

```
 UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
ipc.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; // Or whatever style.
//or
ipc.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whateverColor];
```